# Random polygons in JPanel: Scaled co-ordinates, GridBagLayout and scaled co-ordinates, a different layout manager, or something entirely different?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am generating random polygons in part-random, part-predictable positions in a JPanel (using Polygon class), and lines connecting them (probably using Graphics class, possibly Line2D), for a game I'm creating. (The JPanel is one of a few in a GridBagLayout content pane). When I searched how to generate these polygons, the answers used co-ordinates to generate them (like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113558/check-if-point-is-on-line-in-java-swing) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285226/add-multiple-polygon-objects-on-the-same-jpanel-frame)), which I suppose is not surprising as I don't know how else you would generate them.

However, it seems to me that the only way that co-ordinates could be used is if I used absolute positioning, which is probably a bad idea as it does not support different screen resolutions very well.

A possible solution I'm thinking of is using GridBagLayout as well as using co-ordinates, so that at least it will partly scale to window size, but I don't know whether that will work well. Another solution seems to be to only use scaled co-ordinates.

So either it seems I will need to use absolute positioning with scaled co-ordinates, a layout manager that supports use of co-ordinates but scales them according to window size (I don't think this exists), GridBagLayout and scaled co-ordinates, or come up with a different solution altogether, maybe generating the polygons in a way that does not use co-ordinates? What would you suggest? (or am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: *"it seems to me that the only way that co-ordinates could be used is if I used absolute positioning"* Whoa up there.. it seems your are using the wrong approach. There should only be one painting surface, either a custom painted `JPanel` or a `BufferedImage` displayed in a `JLabel`. Establish a collection of the elements that need to be seen in the 'canvas' and draw each one to a `Graphics` instance when needed.

Comment: No existing LayoutManager can provide what you want.   In particular, GridBagLayout does not act as “coordinates,” since its grid cells are not uniform in size.  Draw your polygons in the overridden paintComponent method of a single JPanel subclass.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try what both of you have suggested. I am not entirely sure what a custom painted JPanel is, does it mean the JPanel is redrawn when the window is resized? Also, should each polygon in the JPanel be contained in separate JLabels, or drawn from the paintComponent() method of the JPanel?

Comment: Also, should I use null layout for the JPanel?

Comment: Tip: Add @VGR (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. *"should I use null layout for the JPanel?"* No.

Comment: There is no need to set the layout at all, since you won’t be adding any child components to it.  As for custom painting, a good place to start is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.  In short:  you create a subclass of JPanel, and override its paintComponent method.  That method is called by the Swing system whenever the underlying desktop wishes to display or redisplay part or all of the window.  So, yes, it will be called when the window resizes (and for many other reasons, almost none of which are under your control).

Comment: @VGR OK I get it now. Thank you both.